# How to sum two unique files with occurrences

Tags: bash

I have two files with unique values and grouped by occurrences using the command `uniq -c`

File1

```
     92 $1 $2 $3
     75 } } } } } '5
     60 D2
     51 $1
     43 D4
```

File2

```
     7 $1 $2 $3
    10 } } } } } '5
     3 D4
```

I'd wish to merge them into a single file, updating occurrences:

```
    99 $1 $2 $3
    85 } } } } } '5
    60 D2
    51 $1
    46 D4
```

Please note that those lines are prefixed with 4 spaces (my local installation of `uniq` adds them). I'm not interested in keeping them, but I just wanted to warn you.
As a final note, please consider that those two files could be very big (at least 100k lines).
Any ideas?

**EDIT** Updated with some real data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk would be of great help herre

```
awk '{array[$2] += $1} END{for ( i in array) print array[i], i}'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk '{array[$2] += $1} END{for ( i in array) print array[i], i}' file1 file2
2 hello
25 foobar
6 dummy
29 test
```

**What it does?**

- `array[$2] += $1` Creates an associative array indexed by the second field. `foobar` `test` etc
- `END{for ( i in array) print array[i], i}` Excecuted at the end of the input. `for` iterates through the array and prints the values.

Comment: the script works great, I have only one problem when the string has one or more spaces. awk reads them as different parts, while they should be grouped together. any ideas?

Comment: It would be little tricky. Did you have any other delimitter seperating numbers and the string part

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be less memory intensive than nu11p01n73R's pure-awk solution, but you'd have to test it

```
sort -k 2,2 File1 File2 | awk '
    NR > 1 && $2 != key {print sum, key; sum=0} 
    {key = $2; sum += $1} 
    END {print sum, key}
'
```

```
6 dummy
25 foobar
2 hello
29 test
```

Pipe into `| sort -nr` to sort by numeric value, descending.